# using va_start in objective c error: 'va_start' used in function with fixed args

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I have defined a variadic method

```
-(void)generateUserGrantDialog:(const char*)msg 
                         Title:(const char*)title 
                           Tag:(int)tag 
                       MsgData:(const char*)mData 
                        MsgLen:(int)mLen 
             CancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelBtnTitle 
             OtherButtonTitles:(NSString *)firstTitle, ... 
                                           NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

Now I have to loop through the va_list , so I wrote the code :

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, firstTitle);
for (NSString *arg = firstTitle; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
{   
     // code
}
va_end(args);
```

When I build the code I get error

Compilation error: 'va_start' used in function with fixed args

Can any one help me get out of it..

Thanks

Comment: Edit your post to show us exactly how you named your variadic method in your `.m` file.  Don't retype it.  Copy and paste the code from your `.m` file.  I'm talking about the line that starts with a `-` or `+` and contains the method's name.

Comment: [See also the Apple documentaiton](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, firstTitle);
for (; firstTitle != nil; firstTitle = va_arg(args, NSString*)) {   
    // code (using each firstTitle)
}
va_end(args);
```